# Is it possible to fetch tweets from X API in the new version (basic level), from specific location?

Tags: python, twitter, tweets

I'm trying to fetch tweets using Tweepy, but many methods are not working for me. Is there any solution for this without resorting to scraping methods?

I try to use:

place
geo
coordinates

geo is contained null in all tweets that I get.